# Importing subpackages while having go.mod/vendor

Tags: go

Is it legal to have sub folders while having a vendor directory?
For example this is my folder structure:

```
src/
src/github.com/MyUser/project/
src/github.com/MyUser/project/main.go
src/github.com/MyUser/project/go.mod
src/github.com/MyUser/project/go.sum
src/github.com/MyUser/project/config/
src/github.com/MyUser/project/config/config.go
src/github.com/MyUser/project/subpackage/subA.go
src/github.com/MyUser/project/vendor/
src/github.com/MyUser/project/vendor/golang.org/...
src/github.com/MyUser/project/vendor/github.com/...
```

When ever I do a go run or build, its looking for the "config", and "subpackage" in vendor directory when it should be within my project itself.
In my main.go I tried the imports with both:

```
import (
  "config"
  "subpackage"
)
```

and

```
import (
  "github.com/MyUser/project/config"
  "github.com/MyUser/project/subpackage"
)
```

I created the config and subpackage for better organization.  I tried with the full path of the config and subpackage, and just the package names; however, can't seem to get it to compile.  Is it possible its trying to retrieve those packages from github.com?

Any advice on what I am doing wrong or different approach?

Comment: `full path of the config and subpackage` - this is suspicious, there is no relative import in go. What are your import lines for these packages in `main.go` ?

Comment: Updated the description.

Comment: What is the output of `go install` command ?

Comment: Show go.mod for help.